# On OS X Safari, is there a way to open a page I had been reading on my iOS device?

Tags: macos, safari, ios, icloud

My iPhone, in its tab organizer screen, shows me open pages on my iPad and even on my computer. (This feature pre-dates iOS 8’s Handoff, going back to at least iOS 7, if not earlier.)

However, whenever I open a new tab in Safari on my MacBook Pro, I never see tabs open on my iOS devices.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a one-sided feature? Ideally, answers don’t require Handoff, and would apply even if the iOS devices in elsewhere.

*As of this writing, I am on the latest iOS and OS X versions (8.1.1 and 10.10.1 Yosemite, respectively).*

Comment: This might be more appropriate on the Apple SE....

Comment: I’m OK with mods moving it…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's visible in the Show all Tabs view, viewable by clicking the Show All Tabs button (located to the left of the Download button in the toolbar), by two-finger pinching on the trackpad, or by choosing Show All Tabs from the View menu.